# How do I make header background image scale at same rate as body background?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a background-image in a fixed navigation bar and the same background-image in the main body of our website.  The goal is to create the effect of the contents going under the navigation when the user scrolls like on this website:
http://bonobomusic.com/news.php

Here is the site I'm building where the problem is:
http://rattletree.com/wordpress2/

When I have the page at full width for my screen everything looks good, but when I resize the window then the background-image in the header is resizing at a different rate than the one on the body.  This is the css I'm using for the header:

```
#main-header{
    position:fixed!important;
    background-image:url("img");
    background-position-y: -62px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I'm seeing that the image in the header is scaling smaller and smaller in both the x and y axis the whole time, and on the background image it scales for a while on both axis but then at a certain point, it is only scaling horizontally and not vertically.  Any help would be appreciated!

Please note: the problem is most obvious when viewing the page at different screen sizes-like a mobile device vs a computer.

Comment: Set the large background image on `body` and remove it from header and anywhere else.

Comment: Then I will lose the whole scrolling under the header effect I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Set your header to full width then give the body and the header the same background image and options. Also make sure the background is centered.

Now add something like this. You will most likely have to remove some of the !importants.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 999px) { 
    body {
        background-size: contain;
    }

    #main-header {
        background-position-y: -30px;
    }
}
```

I used http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ to check upon different screen sizes

Comment: Well it seems to work if I set both to the center and play with the header's Y offset a bit.

Comment: hmm-it is working even when you resize the window down to mobile size?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can comment so I post an answer.

The problem is that your header has a position  with 30px in Y. The easiest way is to set the value to 0px.
Else you'll have to use a second background img for header by removing 30px of the original.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried positioning absolute both the header and body and make them 100% width and height of the window. Then put the background image on both as cover. Then you can make a div that is positioned however far from the top as your header should be and give it overflow hidden.